# Adding text to the section numbering

Tags: sectioning, numbering

I wish to add some text prior to the number given to a subsection, e.g.:

```
Task 1.1  Blablabla
...
Task 1.2  Blablabla
```

How?

Comment: Can you please be a little bit more specific? Do you need this `Task` text for a special environment, like a theorem or for what? BTW: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436)

Comment: Thanks. No special environment. `Task` is just an example text. I would like to have a word like that before the number for a subsection, and that's all.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

To add text before the section, you can use:

```
\renewcommand{\thesection}{Text \arabic{section}}
```

[image]

or for subsection you can use:

```
\renewcommand{\thesubsection}{Text \arabic{section}}
```

[image]

### Code: `section`

```
\documentclass{article}

\renewcommand{\thesection}{Text \arabic{section}}

\begin{document}
\section{First section}
Some text.

\section{Second section}
Some more text.
\end{document}
```

### Code: `subsection`:

```
\documentclass{article}

\renewcommand{\thesubsection}{Text \arabic{subsection}}

\begin{document}
\section{First section}
\subsection{First sub section}
Some text.
\subsection{Second sub section}
Some more text.
\end{document}
```

Comment: This is great and works. But some other problem appears when I use the `\renewcommand{\thesubsection}{Text \arabic{section}}`. The numbering of the subsection suddenly doesn't work. @Peter, if you make two subsections in your example, they both have the number 1. Can that be fixed?

Comment: Clearly LaTeX is not smart enough to know that when I said `\arabic{section}`, that I obviously meant `\arabic{subsection}`.  :-)  Anyway, sorry about that mistake - have updated answer.

Comment: Precisely ;) Thanks alot. (By the way, you must update it in two places in your answer...)

Comment: @Steeven: Two places? Only the `\renewcommand` needed updating. I added two `subsection`s to show that it functioned as desired.

Comment: Oh well, I just meant the single line `\renewcommand{\thesubsection}{Text \arabic{section}}` above your example.

Comment: One side effect I found is that this also inserts the 'Text' in other places such as equation numbers if you have numbered your equations within section numbers.

Answer (score 30):

[Peter's answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/82236/27635) has the disadvantage of printing the text you put before subsection numbers in references to the subsections and in the ToC, as well.

To avoid that, instead of renewing the meaning of `\thesubsection`, it's better to load the `titlesec` package and define

```
\titleformat{\subsection}{\normalfont\large\bfseries}{Task \thesubsection}{1em}{}
```

MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{titlesec}
\titleformat{\subsection}{\normalfont\large\bfseries}{Task \thesubsection}{1em}{}

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\section{A section}
\subsection{First subsection}\label{subsec:first}
Some text from subsection \ref{subsec:second}.
\subsection{Second subsection}\label{subsec:second}
Some text from subsection \ref{subsec:first}.
\end{document}
```

Output:

[image]

If you want similar behavior for sections, you can use something like

```
\titleformat{\section}{\normalfont\Large\bfseries}{Text \thesection}{1em}{}
```

---

If you also want that word before subsection numbers in the ToC, add the following code to your preamble

```
\usepackage[titles]{tocloft}
\renewcommand{\cftsubsecpresnum}{Task\space}
\newlength\mylength
\settowidth\mylength{\cftsubsecpresnum}
\addtolength\cftsubsecnumwidth{\mylength}
```

to get

[image]

Comment: +1, this solution can also be used to add text to the sections without affecting the subsection.