# Aligning text right before section title on same line

Tags: horizontal-alignment, sectioning, text

I am trying align the text "Chapter" before the section title.

I've tried

```
\documentclass[chapterprefix=false]{scrreprt}
\makeatletter
\renewcommand*{\chapterformat}{%
\mbox{\chapapp~\thechapter\autodot:\enskip}%
}
```

And much more got from another answers but it's not working for my issue.

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[latin2]{inputenc}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{ulem}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\graphicspath{ {figures/} }
\usepackage{array}
```

This is what I want [image: Text "Chapter before section title name"]
I am very new to latex. Please help me to solve this problem.
Thank you in advance.

Comment: Welcome to TeX SX! What you want is not very clear. Could you post a small compilable example  showing what your problem is?

Comment: @Bernard i have edited my question. Sorry for not showing the expected output before editing

Comment: Do you  use the `scrreprt` class? B.t.w. in the last code why do you load `inputenc` with option `latin2`, then `utf8`? This is inconsistent!

Comment: @Bernard actually I'm also not sure why i used it. I copied it for something. Can you please tell me what is the efficient way to have the output i want

Comment: The vertical line in the image is  a visualisation of the left margin?

Comment: @Bernard yes it is visualisation of what i want to do

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can load `titlesec` and use this code in your preamble:

```
\usepackage{titlesec}

\titleformat{\chapter}[block]{\LARGE\bfseries\filright}{\chaptertitlename~\thechapter:}{0.5em}{}
```

*Some explanations*:

- The first mandatory argument of `\titleformat}` is the section level.
- The (first) optional argument is the shape used for this level (there are 9 shapes, the default is `hang`).
- The second mandatory argument is the format to be applied to the whole title.
- The third argument defines the label.
- the fourth argument defines the spacing between label and title.
- The fifth argument is code the title body.The very last command can take an argument, which is the title text.
- A second optional argument (not used here), which can be used with some shapes, is for code following the title body.

Comment: Thakn you so much buddy. I got the same solution just before a minute in https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/82235/adding-text-to-the-section-numbering. This solution is working in very efficient way than others i was trying.
+1 for your support. Thank you so much