# How can I change a section header in latex from "1.1 Chickens" to "Article 1.1 Chickens"? in the Appendix?

Tags: sectioning

I need to change the appearance of `sections/subsections` in an `article` in the appendix so that the numbering is preserved, but that the display is not the usual

> 1 Ghosts are real
>
> 1.1 Ghosts are criminals

but rather

> Section 1 Ghosts are real
>
> Article 1.1 Ghosts are criminals

I don't mind manually numbering if that's easier (I'm not an expert with `LaTeX`, so whatever is easier is preferable), but of course if I can do this with automatic numbering, it's less room for error which is a big pro.

It's a tough thing to google so your input is appreciated!

Comment: See https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/252667/82917.

Comment: `\usepackage{chickenize}` :-)

Answer (score 2):

You can change the appearance of `\section` and `\subsection` after `\appendix`.

```latex
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{titlesec}

\begin{document}

\section{Ghosts are real}

\subsection{Ghosts are criminal}

\appendix
\titleformat{\section}
 {\Large\bfseries}
 {Section \thesection}
 {1em}
 {}
\titleformat{\subsection}
 {\large\bfseries}
 {Article \thesubsection}
 {1em}
 {}
\renewcommand{\thesection}{\arabic{section}}

\section{Ghosts are real}

\subsection{Ghosts are criminal}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Without packages:

```latex
\documentclass{article}

\makeatletter
\renewcommand{\@seccntformat}[1]{%
  \ifcsname format#1\endcsname\csname format#1\endcsname\fi
  \csname the#1\endcsname\quad
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\section{Ghosts are real}

\subsection{Ghosts are criminal}

\appendix
\newcommand{\formatsection}{Section }
\newcommand{\formatsubsection}{Article }
\renewcommand{\thesection}{\arabic{section}}

\section{Ghosts are real}

\subsection{Ghosts are criminal}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

As you didn't provide any `MWE`, I assumed that you are using standard class files, and the `MWE` is

```
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage[explicit]{titlesec}

\begin{document}
\makeatletter
\titleformat{\section}[display]{\normalfont\huge\bfseries}{Section \thesection}{20pt}{\huge}
\titleformat{\subsection}[display]{\normalfont\large\bfseries}{Article \thesubsection}{20pt}{\large}
\makeatother

\section{Ghosts are real}

\subsection{Ghosts are criminals}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for this advice and excuses for the lack of MWE! you're correct, it's standard class files as you suggest. The trouble is, that this is in the Appendix, so it appears as "Article 1.1 E.1". Is there any way around this?