# Numbering sections with text instead of Arabic numerals

Tags: sectioning

I would like to replace the Arabic enumeration of the sectioning commands with text-based enumeration. For example, in the following document:

```
\documentclass{scrreprt}

\begin{document}
\chapter{Kingdom}\label{king:a}
This is chapter \ref{king:a}
\section{Phylum} \label{phyl:a}
This is section \ref{phyl:a}.
\subsection{Class}\label{class:a}
This is subsection \ref{class:a}


\chapter*{Kingdom}
This is chapter \textit{Kingdom}.
\section*{Kingdom.Phylum} 
This is section \textit{Kingdom.Phylum}.
\subsection*{Kingdom.Phylum.Class}
This is subsection \textit{Kingdom.Phylum.Class}.

\end{document}
```

[image: Arabic vs text enumeration]

The first chapter is enumerated with a series of Arabic numerals separated by periods. The second chapter is enumerated by text separated by periods. How can I setup a document to automatically enumerate by a section's header instead of Arabic numerals?

#### Notes

- The above example uses the [KOMA document class](https://mirror.las.iastate.edu/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/koma-script/doc/scrguien.pdf) **scrreprt**. A valid answer would not be required to use this document class.
- [This answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/252667/163171) comes close to the desired behavior, but has the disadvantage of the enumerating text is fixed at the redefinition of the section command and not dynamic.
- I am *not* asking about the `enumerate` or `itemize` environments (at least, 75% sure I'm not).

Comment: I assume you don't want such section styling in TOC?

Comment: Actually, a text-enumerated TOC would be preferable, but not required for an accepted answer.

Comment: IMHO such style can make navigations so very painful… (Are you sure you want to do this to your potential readers?)

Comment: @RuixiZhang I think that depends on if the information is arranged into categories (eg a reference manual) or is sequential (eg a textbook).

Answer (score 1):

Since you mentioned that using a **KOMA document class** is not necessary for an acceptable answer, I simply used `book` class. I think you want something like the following:

```
\documentclass{book}

% For referencing current chapter, section etc.
\usepackage{nameref}
\makeatletter
\newcommand*{\currentname}{\@currentlabelname}
\makeatother

\renewcommand{\numberline}[1]{#1~} 

% Using egreg's answer
\usepackage{etoolbox}
% Patch the sectioning commands to provide a hook to be used later
\preto{\chapter}{\def\leveltitle{\chaptertitle}}
\preto{\section}{\def\leveltitle{\sectiontitle}}
\preto{\subsection}{\def\leveltitle{\subsectiontitle}}
\preto{\subsubsection}{\def\leveltitle{\subsubsectiontitle}}

\makeatletter
% \@sect is called with normal sectioning commands
% Argument #8 to \@sect is the title
% Thus \section{Title} will do \gdef\sectiontitle{Title}
\pretocmd{\@sect}
  {\expandafter\gdef\leveltitle{#8}}
  {}{}
% \@ssect is called with *-sectioning commands
% Argument #5 to \@ssect is the title
\pretocmd{\@ssect}
  {\expandafter\gdef\leveltitle{#5}}
  {}{}
% \@chapter is called by \chapter (without *)
% Argument #2 to \@chapter is the title
\pretocmd{\@chapter}
  {\expandafter\gdef\leveltitle{#2}}
  {}{}
% \@schapter is called with \chapter*
% Argument #1 to \@schapter is the title
\pretocmd{\@schapter}
  {\expandafter\gdef\leveltitle{#1}}
  {}{}
\makeatother

\makeatletter
 \patchcmd{\@makechapterhead}{\@chapapp\space \thechapter}{Kingdom:}{}{}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents

\renewcommand{\thechapter}{Kingdom}
\renewcommand{\thesection}{\chaptertitle.Phylum}
\renewcommand{\thesubsection}{\chaptertitle.\sectiontitle.Class}

\chapter{Animalia}

This is chapter \emph{\thechapter\ \currentname}

\section{Arthropoda}

This is section \emph{\thesection\ \currentname}

\subsection{Insecta}

This is subsection \emph{\thesubsection\ \currentname}

\renewcommand{\thechapter}{Kingdom}
\renewcommand{\thesection}{\chaptertitle.Order}
\renewcommand{\thesubsection}{\chaptertitle.\sectiontitle.Family}

\chapter{Plantae}

This is chapter \emph{\thechapter\ \currentname}

\section{Rosales}

This is section \emph{\thesection\ \currentname}

\subsection{Rosacea}

This is subsection \emph{\thesubsection\ \currentname}

\end{document}
```

[image: Animalia]
[image: Plantae]

And you mentioned that text-enumerated TOC is optional. Just in case you want it. I had to use `\renewcommand{\numberline}[1]{#1~}` for natural indention and spacing between the numbering and the title for the TOC, without which the title overlaps with the numbering since the numbering is already too wide.

[image: TOC]

Much of the modification has to do with how they are to be enumerated. So what I did is use egreg's answer from [How to get the current chapter* name, section* name, subsection* name, etc?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/142982/how-to-get-the-current-chapter-name-section-name-subsection-name-etc) for passing the current chapter, section etc. for the commands concerned with their enumeration.